# POST request message to a URL takes abnormal time

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to POST to a URL on the click of a button (to enable trigger pulse of the  camera). I have a similar code to disable trigger pulse on the click of a button. The problem i face is that there is an abnormally high delay for the action to get completed. I could not figure out why it completes early sometimes and takes large time sometimes. Can someone help ?

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string requestmethod = "POST";
        string postData = "";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        string URL = "http://192.168.0.42/entrig.cgi";
        string contenttype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request = null;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        Stream dataStream;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
        request.Method = requestmethod;
        request.ContentType = contenttype;
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Started Trigger");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes your web application needs to restart if it has been idle for a while. Does the server respond more quickly on the 2nd and subsequent requests?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to assume the server is being consistent. Try monitoring what is no the wire (e.g. with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) and see where the slow down is.